# ColdFusion session variable is GONE in IE11

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

My coldfusion session variable failed in IE. I have no problem with maintaining the session across pages in FireFox and Chrome. Similar question has been posted here and the solution was to check J2EE session variable in Administrator. The different in my case is that I have J2EE session checked in Admin page and also I have the following in my `Application.cfc`

```
<cfset THIS.Name ="New_Site_Version1"/>
<cfset THIS.ApplicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,30,0) />
<cfset THIS.SessionManagement ="YES"/>
<cfset THIS.SessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan( 0,0,30,0 ) />
<cfset THIS.SetClientCookies = "YES" />

 <cffunction name="OnSessionStart" access="public" returntype="void" output="false">
       <CFIF IsDefined("URL.user_ID")>
       <CFSET SessionObj = New cfcomponents.Main.ManageSessions()>
       <CFSET SessionObj.CreateUserSessions(URL.user_ID)>
    </CFIF>
 </cffunction>
```

I also have session cookies checked in Admin

When I checked, the session was created in Application.cfc but soon after I clicked on a link, it's gone!
It only happen in IE.

Is there any work around?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but 30 minutes is a rather short settting for an application timeout.  The default, I believe, is 48 hours.

Comment: I changed that but this is still in my testing phase. I found out that if I lower my IE browser setting to "Low" (tools>Internet Options>Privacy tab) then the problem go away. The problem is, it is not possible to ask my users to reset their browser every time they are using my web app. This is quite annoying and frustrating. is it just me that experiencing this issue?

Comment: What exactly is causing the lost session? is the cookie being lost the moment you go to another page? or is it being lost when you navigate away from the app? when is it being lost? If the browser is set to not keep cookies... there's nothing you can do. (well, i mean other than url tokens.)

Comment: Maybe IE security settings that doesn't keep cookies?

Answer (score 0):

"This" application scope is not the "Session" application scope.  You may need to review your variable scope when instantiating variables that should be available to other modules in your application.  You can do that here:

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09af4-7ff1.html

When you instantiate a ColdFusion application you use the CFAPPLICATION tag detailed here:

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d69.html